# Send a "simple integer" from one script to another

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Using the `input.source` instruction I can access a "series" variable (float or integer) from one script to another.

However, this instruction doesn't seem to support "simple" variables. It only supports "series". If it were to support "simple" variables, the second script below would not issue this error: `Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'calc_bars_count'='bars'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.`

**script 'A'**

```
//@version=5
indicator("A")
bars = 100
plot(bars, title="Nr. of bars")
```

**script 'B'**

```
//@version=5
indicator("B")
bars = input.source(title='Nr. of bars', defval=close)
c = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close, calc_bars_count=bars)
plot(c)
```

So, is there any way to send a "simple integer" from script "A" to script "B" or find a workaround solution to stop script "B" from generating any error? What is important is that the number of bars is set in the first script, but used in the second script. Please note that these two scripts serve purely as an example to what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this scenario.

`input.source()` always returns a `series` variable.

There is no way in Pine Script to convert `series` variables to any of the lower types; `simple`, `input` and `const`.